# Schedule a web page to run automatically at regular intervals of time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to Request one of my webpage at a regular time on every day.After first request,I done the page cached.

Can anyone help how to send  automatic request for  webpage ?

Comment: where do you want to send the request from? winforms application? What have you tried?

Comment: I have a webapplication,it have a chart page.the first page load time for the chart page is too high ,so I cached the page.and I need to first run the page automatically on after 12am everyday

Comment: If you want a page to run by a request at regular intervals, use a Windows Service with a timer with a regular interval. That is what timers and Windows Services are for. Other than that, there isn't much of another way. If you are caching the page then there isn't much of a benefit of invoking the page if its just cached unless you are refreshing the cache at a certain time or event.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Quartz.net. You can schedule the page load in a quartz job,  and trigger it with a cron.

Alternatively you can try set up an account at uptimerobot.com. (assuming your site is publicly accessible) and set up a ping test on that page

Comment: Sorry should have added, quartz is a library you add to your system.  Uptimerobot.com is a free cloud pinging service that tests if a page is running

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of doing this. But if you are wanting something cached and you are rellying on this mechanism then I think you are doing something wrong. Maybe can you explain exactly what you are trying to do? What are you trying to cache and what platforms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Normally on a Linux-Server you have cronjobs. There you can set your own intervall.

If you dont have cronjobs by yourself, there are many free services where you can create a cronjob